# DropDownList BackColor In IE

Tags: asp.net

How do I change DropDownList BackColor  in IE?In Firefox it paints correctly whole DropDown,but In IE there always remains white color in border of DropDown

Comment: What IE-Version? I don't see any difference between Firefox 4, IE9 and Chrome 11.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following tags:

```
<html>
<title>Select Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
..foo { background: black; color:white; }
..bar { background: transparent; color: red;}
</style>

<select style="background:yellow; color: red;">
<option style="background:green;color:white;">Abelone</option>
<option class="foo">Banana</option>
<option class="bar">Cantaloupe</option>
</select>
</html>
```